# How to create UI for 2D games?

Tags: flash, ui-design, flixel, haxe, flash-develop

I'm working on a game using Haxe + Flambe but I'm having a hard time making the UI part of it (main screen, level selection, etc).

And I began to think... is there another way?

I would love to have something like Flash, I mean, WYSIWYG like to make the UI. Just because I don't want to spend my time coding the screens until they look like what's on my mind.

**So the questions are:**

How do people work?

Is there something visual to make the UI for games that'll be programmed on Haxe (it doesn't matter if using OpenFL, Flambe or other)?

Answer (score 1):

There is this [haxe ui builder](http://haxeui.org/try.jsp) you might want to check out.

In general however, if such a tool doesn't exist or doesn't give you what you want, what might help is to create the UI using an image editing program (like Flash/Animate or Photoshop). You can edit and fine tune it until you are happy with it, and when you are done write the code manually. This way you only really have to write the code once, and you already know what it's going to look like.